# Сравнение полей DateField в Django

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно осуществить сравнение двух полей DateField. Поля создаются из модели:

```
class forma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = new_form
        widgets = {
            'date_1': SelectDateWidget(years=range(2010, 2015),
            'date_2': SelectDateWidget(years=range(2010, 2015),
        }

        def clean_date_1(self):
             date_1 = self.cleaned_data.get('date_1', None)
             date_2 = self.cleaned_data.get('date_2', None)
             if date_2:
                  if date_1 >= date_2:
                      raise ValidationError("Дата1 не может быть позже Дата2")
             return date_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А проблема в том, что вообще не выполняется условие if date_2?
Уж не из-за того ли, что и в модели тоже date_2 определяется позже, чем date_1?
Проверьте этот нюанс.
Наверняка эта же проверка сработает в методе clean_date_2. Есть такая особенность в обработке полей формы.

Answer (score 0):

Сомнительно название "new_form" для модели...

Если Вы пишите clean_ метод валидации данных, которые придут, например, методом POST из типичной html-формы, то переведите в этом методе полученные строки в даты через strptime и сравнивайте, как хотели.

Comment: Делаю так:

def clean(self):

        startDate = self.cleaned_data.get('startDate', None)
        endDate = self.cleaned_data.get('endDate', None)

        if endDate:
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(startDate, '%d%m%Y') >= datetime.datetime.strptime(endDate, '%d%m%Y'):
                raise ValidationError("Дата начала проекта не может быть позже его окончания")
        return startDate

Не работает.

Comment: странный формат '%d%m%Y', покажите пример даты, которую вводите в браузере в поле даты. Если там виджет скриптовый что-то перерисовывает, то значение value от input скопируйте.

Comment: Дата вводится посредством SelectDateWidget и в итоговой таблице в браузере отображается как 31 марта 2014 г. В models.py эти поля прописаны следующим образом:

    startDate = models.DateField(u'Дата начла проекта', default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

Comment: Ну так тут .strftime("%d.%m.%Y"), а там '%d%m%Y', Вы действительно разницы не видите?

И "Не работает" понятие растяжимое.. Место и тип ошибки конкретнее опишите

Comment: Это я уже поправил. А ошибка вот такая: 

>must be string, not datetime.date

Comment: Ну, значит, там уже дата, с ней можно работать, в какой строке ошибка?